# Q: How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?

Tags: api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

How do I get a **YouTube video thumbnail** from the YouTube API?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)